# Dealing with holidays and multiple files in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, file, spring-batch

I have a `spring batch` application that needs to:

1. Read two files named `PriceA_yyyy_mm_dd.csv` and `PriceB_yyyy_mm_dd.csv`
2. Process the lines into object
3. Write to the database

I have managed to `read`, `process` and  `write` to the database, however need help on dealing with holidays when the files are not available in the directory and in which case, I need to fetch the last available file and process and write for the day.

Given I have pre-defined holidays for the files:

-PriceA* File

```
15-Feb
16-Feb
19-Feb
20-Feb
21-Feb
05-Apr
06-Apr
30-Apr
```

-PriceB* File

```
15-Feb
16-Feb
19-Feb
20-Feb
21-Feb
29-Mar*
30-Mar*
02-Apr*
05-Apr
06-Apr
```

The corresponding file will not be available on their respective holidays in which case I need to grab the last available file.

My question is how can I factor this into my Spring batch application and are there any strategies to do so.

```
@Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception {
        if (todayIsHoliday(propertyHolder.getHolidays())) {

            //holiday logic
        }

        JobParameters jobParameters = buildJobParameters();
        jobLauncher.run(reminderJob, jobParameters);
    }
```

Where can I keep the defined list of holidays? How can I arrange the workflow in my spring batch application to factor in holidays? Should I have multiple jobs for each file?

Comment: How does the job currently look up the file it is supposed to be processing?  Is it passed in with jobParameters?

Comment: @JoeChiavaroli in main run() method, I’m setting two files as String extracting from Enum, one for PriceA and one for PriceB. Then setting A and B files in jobParameter. Two tasklets one for each file then extracts their respective filename and downloads. Then in my job subsequent step is read, process and write. Since my post, I have kept holidays in the database for enums PriceA and PriceB. Any better way?

Comment: It doesn't seem to me that you need to keep a list of holidays.  When you check for the file to exist, and it doesn't exist, you can infer that it is a holiday - is that correct?  If that is the case, when the file doesn't exist, always look for the previous day's file.. and continue to do so until you've found the last available file.

Comment: @Joe hmm in my case it involves users creating these files manually daily except on holidays so I did want the idea of processing last files and look for correct previous working day file as per requirement